# '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path

Tags: wpf, animation, binding, storyboard

I have an animation on the border

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5E5E5E"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**It works at runtime.**

But at design time I get the following error:

**`'[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[1].(2)'.`**

Can someone explain to me what this means?

**EDIT:**

The use of animation is in control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GrayButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Border 
            x:Name="Border"  
            CornerRadius="0" 
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.9"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5E5E5E"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF818181"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.9"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF383838"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5A5A5A"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5A5A5A"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF383838"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFBCBCBC"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFABABAB"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter 
                Margin="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Show us the XAML you have for the Border TargetName.  My guess is you don't have a panel inside of it, and if you do, there isn't > 1 gradient stop?

Comment: @NETscape. The use of animation is in control template of button, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [`bug`](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694540/vs-designer-issue) of Visual Studio, I can confirm this on the 2010 version. In this situation, try to set the name for `GradientStop`:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop x:Name="MyStop1"  <---- Here
                  Color="White"
                  Offset="0" />

    <GradientStop x:Name="MyStop2"  <---- Here
                  Color="White"
                  Offset="0.9" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

And use like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GrayButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"  
            CornerRadius="0" 
            BorderThickness="1">

        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop x:Name="MyStop1" Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="MyStop2" Color="White" Offset="0.9"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="MyStop2">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF5E5E5E"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="MyStop2">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF818181"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" Storyboard.TargetName="MyStop1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.9"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

    ...
```

Comment: It gives the following error: `'Color' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Border'`.

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom: `TargetName` should be the name of your GradientStop (in my case `MyStop2`), not the name of `Border`.